# Attempting to install netgear N300 Wireless USB Adapter on Ubuntu without a present internet connection

Tags: wireless, usb, software-installation, adapter, netgear

Hello Linux/Ubuntu world out there. I don't have internet presently on the desktop I am trying to install the USB wireless adapter on. This seems to be the problem, which if the hardware would work would theoretically fix the problem. I can NOT access the internet via anything but wireless. I am presently on my laptop searching for answers while trying to install this little device. So any advice will have to take that into account.

Now I have tried so far, using WINE which does not want to work, I have tried Windows Wireless Drivers which doesn't want to work, I have tried Software Sources, Other Software and it will not acknowledge the cdrom as a repository stating errors like E:Unable to stat the mount point /cdrom/ -stat (2: No such file or directory) However I can open the CD icon on my computer and access and browse the files. The computer can read the CD. I can read the CD.

I've tried just plugging it in and seeing if the computer will automatically recognize the hardware, and go from there. That does not work either. I have tested USB port to just verify that the USB port works. It does. My laptop recognizes the hardware, and would easily install the software if I prompted it to. The difference is that my laptop is Vista, and I HATE Vista.

Any tips, tricks?

Edit command lsusb: Bus 008-004  with various ids Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub (basically recognizing my mouse, keyboard, and the netgear is connected) and then for the command arch: I get i686

What does this stuff mean?

I know the equipment is not bad, I just don't know how to make them communicate with each other.

Second Edit: 
This is what the package says: N300 WNA3100,

This is what the terminal says: Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0846: 9020 NetGear, Inc.

That is all it says. There is nothing following after that.

Answer (score 2):

OP Posted:

> I FIGURED IT OUT! I installed the driver: bcmwlhigh5.inf, using ndiswrapper (don't ask me what version, I don't know) to check stats and window wireless drivers to install I was able to get the device working and communicating! That is awesome.